# Fragment to Fragment EditText

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I would like to pass my EditText input from my first fragment to the textview on the second fragment on button click. But textview displays "null" value when button click is triggered.

First Fragment:

```
 @Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.first_frag, container, false);

    TextView tv = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tvFragFirst);
    tv.setText(getArguments().getString("msg"));

    Button btn = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.tryBtn);
    btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                               @Override
                               public void onClick(View v) {
                                   EditText woo = (EditText)v.findViewById(R.id.editText);
                                   MainActivity.myBundle.putString("Try", String.valueOf(woo));
                                   switch (v.getId()) {
                                       case R.id.tryBtn:
                                      SecondFragment home = new SecondFragment();
                                           FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                                           ft.replace(R.id.first_frag, home);
                                           ft.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_ENTER_MASK);
                                           ft.addToBackStack(null);
                                           ft.commit();
                                           break;
                                   }
                               }
                           }
    );

    return v;
}
```

Second Fragment:

```
 @Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.second_frag, container, false);

    TextView tv = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tvFragSecond);
    TextView tvTry = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tvTry);
    String myValue = (String) MainActivity.myBundle.get("Try");

    return v;
}
```

MainActivity:

```
public static Bundle myBundle = new Bundle();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code,

First Fragment

```
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater,  ViewGroup container,  Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.first_frag, container, false);

//        TextView tv = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tvFragFirst);
//        tv.setText(getArguments().getString("msg"));


        final EditText woo = (EditText)v.findViewById(R.id.editText);

        Button btn = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.tryBtn);
        btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                SecondFragment home = new SecondFragment();

                Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                bundle.putString("Try", woo.getText().toString());
                home.setArguments(bundle);

                FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                ft.replace(R.id.first_frag, home);
                ft.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_ENTER_MASK);
                ft.addToBackStack(null);
                ft.commit();

            }
        });

        return v;
    }
```

Second Fragment

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,  Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.second_frag, container, false);

    TextView tv = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tvFragSecond);
    TextView tvTry = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tvTry);

    Bundle arguments = getArguments();
    if (arguments != null) {
        String myValue  = arguments.getString("Try");
        tvTry.setText(myValue);
    }


    return v;
}
```

and remove this line in your MainActivity, it's better not using static bundle.

```
public static Bundle myBundle = new Bundle();
```

Comment: Thank you very much. This worked perfectly.. How about if I'm gonna add multiple values on button click?

Comment: just put it in the bundle which have been created: 
 bundle.putString("secondTry", woo2.getText().toString()); and then get it from argument: String myValue2  = arguments.getString("secondTry");

Answer (score 1):

what about calling `newInstance` with parameters?

```
SecondFragment.newInstance(/*your text*/)  //when you open your fragment

//in your Second Fragment
 public static SecondFragment newInstance(String data) {
    SecondFragment sFragment = new SecondFragment ();
    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putString("data", data);
    sFragment.setArguments(bundle);
    return sFragment;
    }
```

Comment: You forgot to add this line : bundle.putString("Try", woo.getText().toString()); in your code.

Comment: I'm sorry. But where do I put SecondFragment.newInstance(/*your text*/) and what to put inside "your text", also which fragment do I put the public static SecondFragment newInstance(String data) {
    SecondFragment sFragment = new SecondFragment ();
    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putString("data", data);
    sFragment.setArguments(bundle);
    return sFragment;
    } 
? 
I'm very sorry. I am new to Android development.

Comment: first line you should put here
`SecondFragment home = SecondFragment.newInstance("HERE YOU PUT ANY STRING OR DATA WHICH YOU WANT") ;`

other things you put in your Second fragment

Answer (score 0):

Use Bundle for that, show below code;

```
  Fragment fragment = new SecondFragment();
  FragmentManager fm =getSupportFragmentManager();
  FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
  ft.replace(R.id.frame_layout, fragment);
  ft.commit();

  Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
  bundle.putString("id", woo.getText().toString());
  fragment.setArguments(bundle);
```

and get this value in `SecondFragment` like below code;

```
Bundle bundle = this.getArguments();
      if (bundle != null) {
         String id  = bundle.getString("id");
      }
tv.setText(id);
```

Answer (score 0):

About your statement :

> But textview displays "null" value when button click is triggered.

This is NOT the way to get a text from editText

```
EditText woo = (EditText)v.findViewById(R.id.editText);
String.valueOf(woo)
```

try this one:

```
woo.getText().toString()
```

About passing information between fragments I use [EventBus](https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus)

It uses the Observer pattern:

You subscribes to an event:

```
@Subscribe(threadMode = ThreadMode.MAIN)  
public void onMessageEvent(MessageEvent event) {/* Do something */};
```

You post events:

```
EventBus.getDefault().post(new MessageEvent());
```

That will work if you have both fragments at the same time.
Considering your logic you do not have both fragments. So I would do the next:

Your fragment should call your activity like:

```
mainActivity.onSentInputField(woo.getText().toString());
```

And your activity will be responsible for changing the fragment with the correct information. This way you code is more organized and the fragments are being changed in one single place.

Comment: Have you think this is right way to pass data between two Fragment ?